# Regexp groups selection

Tags: regex, go

I'm stuck with log parsing. I've this rows in log file. Everything ends with line end `\n`

```
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:125] VersionInfo\886
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:109][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->IncomingTime\16
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:109][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->IncomingData\397
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:109][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->ThreadID\8
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:109][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->RequestExecuteStart\16
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:109][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->RequestInfo\25
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:109][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->CheckUserInfo\139
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:218]->Start RTS
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:640][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->StartExecuteTask\35
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:749][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->EndExecuteTask\36
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:749][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->RequestExecuteEnd\16
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:749][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->OutgoingData\26651
```

I want to parse each row in groups - time, traceid (if exists) and block name.
To select datetime (which is always there) i use `\[(.*?)\]`. It's first group.
Next must be traceid, if it exists. Get separator `(?:\[|->| )` - `[` or `->` or . Group select is same as first `\[(.*?)\]`. And then goes third group with block name `([a-zA-Z ]+)` - any text at the end without numbers.

I'm completely confused with how to connect it all.
What i want to get is:

- group 1 - datetime
- group 2 - traceid | zero
- group 3 - block name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick: `^\[(.*?)\](?:\[(.*?)\])?->([a-zA-Z ]+)`. Make sure you're using the multi-line flag. Here's a Python demo:

```
>>> for x in re.finditer(r'^\[(.*?)\](?:\[(.*?)\])?->([a-zA-Z ]+)', file, re.M):
    print(x.group(1), x.group(2), x.group(3))
2018.07.10 00:30:03:109 TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91 IncomingTime
2018.07.10 00:30:03:109 TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91 IncomingData
2018.07.10 00:30:03:109 TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91 ThreadID
2018.07.10 00:30:03:109 TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91 RequestExecuteStart
2018.07.10 00:30:03:109 TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91 RequestInfo
2018.07.10 00:30:03:109 TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91 CheckUserInfo
2018.07.10 00:30:03:218 None Start RTS
2018.07.10 00:30:03:640 TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91 StartExecuteTask
2018.07.10 00:30:03:749 TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91 EndExecuteTask
2018.07.10 00:30:03:749 TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91 RequestExecuteEnd
2018.07.10 00:30:03:749 TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91 OutgoingData
```

You could make it only give you the actual trace ID using `^\[(.*?)\](?:\[TraceID: (.*?)\])?->([a-zA-Z ]+)`.

Comment: @DigitalGod Happy to help. If I'm not mistaken, you have enough rep for upvoting _and_ downvoting now.